# How to embed IE in Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, browser

While I was using Delphi I remember simple WebBrowser object that used IE and was really easy to use. Is there an option to embed IE in Swing application? I'm not looking for new implementation of web browser (i found some rather expensive ones on web), but just the free option of embedding IE or some other browser in application.

Answer (score 3):

[DJ Native Swing](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/) does that. I've used its `JWebBrowser` component and it worked well.
You will have to bundle your app with the SWT libraries though.

[image]