# How do I style HTML correctly using an external CSS file?

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jeditorpane

I want to be able to load an HTML document from the Internet, display it in a JEditorPane and have it styled in Java using both an external CSS file and/or from any `<style>...</style>` tags. What I'm doing right now is using `jEditorPane.setPage(URL);` and it's not correctly styled.

Comment: There's a lot of moving parts to this question...could you be more specific?

Comment: *"I want to be able to load an HTML document from the Internet, .. correctly styled."*  `JEditorPane` has not a snowball's chance in Hades of rendering HTML off the World Wild Web as we might expect to see it in FF or Chrome unless it is from a limited range of documents that we control (and that are very simple).  Otherwise use a different component (perhaps something from JavaFX).

Comment: @Makoto I would like to use an external CSS file to style an HTML document off of the internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I style HTML in a JEditorPane?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061665/how-do-i-style-html-in-a-jeditorpane)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the JavaDoc - jEditorPane supports the *bleeding edge* [HTML 3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) and [CSS1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/) so the short answer is, you really don't want to try rendering modern web pages with it.

However, you may be able to do this:

```
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet;

HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
jEditorPane.setEditorKit(kit);

URL url = new URL(location of your stylesheet);
StyleSheet styleSheet = new StyleSheet();
styleSheet.importStyleSheet(url)
kit.setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can render modern HTML with a `JEditorPane`.  From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html):

> By default, the following types of content are known:
>
> ...
>
> **text/html**
>
> > HTML text. The kit used in this case is the class `javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit` which provides HTML 3.2 support.

[HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32), as defined last century, ie no CSS/CSS2.

You could use an external library to render HTML as we know it now.  A little bit of google work will turn up a couple of options, or you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315726/how-to-embed-ie-in-swing-application).